# How to load data from text file to table in odi 12c mapping?

Tags: mapping, etl, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to load data from text file to a table. The mapping executes successfully but no data is loaded to the staging table. I am using LKM FILE TO SQL and SQL Control Append as IKM. Staging table is created but not loading the rows to the table, insert rows is 0

Comment: can you share your codes

Comment: In the datastore i created, data is not visible when i select view data

Answer (score 0):

As I observed you doesn't created the datastore properly, for a text file you have to manually give the proper conditions like fixed or delimited file and then what about delimited separator(,|,..etc) and then  view the data . After giving all these you can view your data i.e columns and check whether the datatype is correct or not then creat source file in the model